# ListLinePlot two datasets with two different colors

Tags: plotting, color

Is there a way to use single `ListLinePlot`? I don't like my solution.

Here is a minimal example.

```
SeedRandom@2;
xdata = RandomInteger[5, {3, 20}];
ydata = xdata + 10;
Show[ListLinePlot[xdata, PlotStyle -> ColorData[97, 1]], 
 ListLinePlot[ydata, PlotStyle -> ColorData[97, 2]], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: plot]

I don't know why this doesn't work

```
ListLinePlot[{xdata, ydata}, 
 PlotStyle -> {ColorData[97, 1], ColorData[97, 2]}]
```

Comment: `{{list1, list2}, {list3, list4}}` as first argument does not work; you need to have `{list1,list2,list3,list4}`.

Comment: You have a list of lists of lists, and that is too much nesting for `ListLinePlot[]` to style properly. As the answers to your question suggest, you need to do some flattening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ListLinePlot[Riffle[xdata, ydata], PlotStyle -> (ColorData[97] /@ {1, 2})]
```

[image]

A more cumbersome alternative,

```
ListLinePlot[Join@@{xdata, ydata}, PlotStyle -> (ColorData[97] /@ {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2})]
```

> same picture

You can also wrap each data set with `Style` and assign its color:

```
ListLinePlot[Join @@ 
  MapIndexed[Function[{x, p}, Style[#, ColorData[97, p[[1]]]] & /@ x], {xdata, ydata}, 1]]
```

> same picture

Comment: When I added more option for `PlotStyle`, it does not work. Say I wanna set AbsoluteThickness@4

Comment: @Okkes, you can use `PlotStyle->(Directive[AbsoluteThickness[4],,ColorData[97]@#]&/@{1,2})`

Comment: your work around works only two cluster data set. What if I have three or more data set?

Comment: Sorry, your last solution works! But I would like to use custom color for each cluster, say, `col0 = {Red, Darker@Green, Blue};`

Comment: `ListLinePlot[
 Join @@ MapIndexed[
   Function[{x, p}, Style[#, col0[[p]]] & /@ x], {A15, A30, A60}, 1]]` This works!!

Answer (score 1):

```
SeedRandom@2;
xdata = RandomInteger[5, {3, 20}];
ydata = xdata + 10;
Show[ListLinePlot[#,PlotStyle -> ColorData[97, #[[1, 1]]]] & /@ {xdata, ydata}, 
PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]